# How to connect to php in android using an async task?

Tags: php, android, asynchronous

I want to retrieve data from a php file on my server from an android application. I have been searching for a working example for 2 days now and all I can found is this:

http://www.androidaspect.com/2013/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php.html
http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

I have also looked at a great number of similar questions on SO, but my attempts to recreate this have been futile. So please excuse me if you think my question as a duplicate.

I basically want to retrieve echoed php data on a php script like this:

```
<?php
echo "Hello PHP";
?>
```

and display it in a TextView.

Here is my Main activity code called Home_Activity.java

```
package com.example.httppost;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TextView to display result
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_display);
    new GetData(textView).execute("");
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private TextView display;

GetData(TextView view){
    this.display = view;
}

 protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpGet request;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    String result = "error";
    // TextView to display result

    // Try to connect using Apache HttpClient Library
    try {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        request = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8080/food.php");
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // Code to handle exception
        result = "error";
    }

    // response code
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            // Appending result to textview
            result = result + line ;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Code to handle exception
        result = "error";
    }
    return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.display.setText(result);
}

}}
```

The error log looks like hieroglyphics. The program executes briefly and then I get the dreaded "Unfortunately home_automation has stopped."
I think it has to do with me attempting to set the textView within the Async task but I have no idea how to fix that or whether or not my code for sending the http request is correct.
What I do know is that the php and server stuff is correct.
All tutorials show how to do this within the main thread. When i did that i kept getting a Network on main tread error message thing. This is my first app using http requests and Async tasks.
I am border lining insanity. Please help by showing me where i went wrong and thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my stacktrace:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.httppost.MainActivity$GetData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:69)
at com.example.httppost.MainActivity$GetData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am 99% sure that the problem lies in the the   `textView.setText(result);`
I have edited my code but I'm still getting the NullPointer exception

Comment: Why your app crashes you should find in the LogCat (the cause, and the line number where it crashes). However, at the end of the first tutorial it is said: `One thing you need to keep in mind is that - " always use the localhost address http://10.0.2.2 in place of http://localhost"`. And I see you are omitting this, which will create further troubles for you.

Comment: Are you running the program on the emulator and is localhost your PC? Because if localhost refers to your android phone it will not work since you don't have an apache server on the phone.

Comment: @Andy i have changed it from localhost to http://10.0.2.2 and looked at the error log, I'll try to make sense of it  and edit my question.

Comment: @Day I am running this on an emulator.

Comment: @Diaan4u okay, I also noticed that you have a '/' at the end of your adress and I'm not sure if this leads you to the php file

Comment: your url should be : `http://10.0.2.2:8080/food.php` instead of `http://localhost:8080/food.php/`

Comment: @Houcine I changed the url and it is still giving the same result. I strongly doubt that the url is my main problem

Comment: @Diaan4u : you should add the stacktrace of the exception you got. are using Wamp Server ?? if yes, check if it is onLine ( right click => put Online )

Comment: @Houcine I have added my stack trace to my question. I have a manually installed Apache2.4 server with php 5 that is online.

Comment: Well your result is null. Try setting `String result = "error"` instead of `null`, then you will have no more exception. There is still some bug in the `doInBackground(..)`-method

Comment: @Day I did what you said. The exception is still there. I think the nullpointer is the textView that is "non-existent" within the asynctask? still unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys i feel like such a noob. Must have accidentally deleted the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Which explains why the application was stopping prematurely.
I also forgot to instantiate the TextView in my Async class which explains the null pointer. Thank you all for the comments and help!