# How do I print PHP echo on my android app?

Tags: php, android, bufferedinputstream

I'm fairly new to android and PHP programming and I am currently running into a problem printing my echo statement from my php page, which is as simple as:

```
    <?php
    echo "Hey there response!";
    ?>
```

What I am currently using in my MainActivity is:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    //ASYNC WAY
    new GetData(txtView).execute("");
```

Where AsyncTask is defined by:

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private TextView display;


    GetData(TextView view){
        this.display = view;
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... message){
        HttpClient httpclient;
        HttpGet request;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String result = "error0";
        try{
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/php/wamp.php");
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e){
            result = "error1";
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line="";
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                result = result + line;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            result = "error2";
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.display.setText(result);
    }
}
```

The message in the txtView becomes error2, and I have no idea why.

**EDIT**
I was originally using a non-AsyncTask method of reading in input stream but I have switch to AsyncTask due to Networking error. The problem still persists though since I am not getting the corrent echo in my application.

Comment: Perhaps its problem with with my url since localhost isn't seen on the emulator or the phone that I am testing this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too late for yanki but for anybody else that comes across this page.

I tried it with yanki's code and got the same error as him "error 2". I noticed then that I hadn't **updated the manifest file** to allow internet permissions.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I ran it again and it worked perfectly. So using yanki's code and entering the internet permissions in the manifest file the program should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
The problem was you are reading it as byte, you weren't converting it back to `char`

```
private String readStream(String url) {
        try {
                  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                  InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                  String result = "";

    // convert response to string
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                  InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                  int intch;
                  while ((intch = r.read()) != -1) {
                    char ch = (char) intch;
                    // Log.i("app", Character.toString(ch));
                    String s = new String(Character.toString(ch).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    sb.append(s);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
             } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: I have, but when I try using your code, that is doing the echo reading in a separate method, the result output in empty. First it gave me an error at v.setText(s); so instead I tried using a Toast which ended up being empty.

Comment: Try `Log.i` Just before `result= sb.toString();` To find if its getting value or not

Comment: There was a Networking error which I think is fixed by running the reading as Async task, which I am trying by using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056528/how-to-connect-to-php-in-android-using-an-async-task) , but I am getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated code, I am not longer getting the NullPointerException but it is still not doing what it is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you jst use JSON or XML in sending whatever value you want to be displayed in your android app... try these [try these](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)