# Print PHP Echo On Android App

Tags: php, android, admob

Im trying to acheive a way to print a json echo in android code; but not just a simple echo but an admob code; so that admob ad unit will be in the json file in the server and i call it into android code as follow: Json file is as follow:

```
{
"ads":{     
    "inter":"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
}
}
```

Is it possible to do this? so i can change the admob code from the file in the server without updating the app in the store?
If so what the android code will be responsible to fetch that string into the app.

My code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private List<Song> songList;
private SongAdapter songAdapter;

// URL of object to be parsed
String JsonURL = "http://xxxxx.com/ads.json";
// This string will hold the results
String data = "";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
//TODO: full screen ad
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
//TODO: selected item
private int mPosition;

String[] names = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"};

String[] singers = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"};

int[] pics = {
        R.drawable.tip1,
        R.drawable.tip1,
        R.drawable.tip1,
        R.drawable.tip1,
        R.drawable.tip1,
        R.drawable.tip1};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    setupActionBar();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("ads");

                        String Inter = obj.getString("inter");
                        data = Inter;

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(obreq);

    //Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes in
    //the content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    //using a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

   //use this in case of gridlayoutmanager
   //mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

   //use this in case of Staggered GridLayoutManager
   //mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);


     mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //intializing an arraylist called songlist
    songList = new ArrayList<>();

    //adding data from arrays to songlist
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        Song song = new Song(names[i], singers[i], i + 1, pics[i]);
        songList.add(song);
    }
    //initializing adapter
    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(songList);

    //specifying an adapter to access data, create views and replace the content
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
    songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            // TODO: check condition it should whether show ad or not
            Integer[] adPositions = {1,2}; // list of ad positions

            if (!Arrays.asList(adPositions).contains(position)) {
                goToItem(position);
                return;
            }

            // TODO: check ad is loaded before showing
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mPosition = position;
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                goToItem(position);
            }
        }
    }));


    // TODO:init ad
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(data);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            goToItem(mPosition);
        }
    });

    //TODO: load new ad
    requestNewInterstitial();
}

//TODO: load new ad
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

//TODO: open item at position
private void goToItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test1Activity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test2Activity.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test3Activity.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test4Activity.class));
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test5Activity.class));
            break;
        case 5:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test6Activity.class));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

**EDIT**

The code works fine except one thing that is the app crashes (sometimes) when i click to open an activity that going to show the interstitial code before togo to the item. i dont want the app to crash anymore.

i think sometimes cant connect to server thats why it crashes (this only on interstitial) nativeExpress always fine either connect or not.

i dont want the app to crash anymore, is there anyway to verify connection to server, or force it first to connect to server if success > load > show
if not connect to server just ignore and go to the item.

Comment: Pretty stamdard to call a php script in Android code and read its echos. Whats the problem?

Comment: Thank you for answering, the problem is that i have no knowledge on how to do it, i tried this way here but couldn't figure it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177821/how-do-i-print-php-echo-on-my-android-app , can you help with a code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` in PHP sends text to client via HTTP(S) connection.

So, as I understood, you want to retrieve admob id from your server to show admob banner using particular value of id.

to retrieve some data you can use any library you want.

E.g., volley lib  https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

or, JSOUP library https://jsoup.org/download

```
`compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'`
```

usage

`Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();`

**EDIT**

I would like to say that you have to initialize interstitial only after you retrieve the `data` variable (that is, admob key).

I your current code you try to inialize interstital before you retrieve to callback.

What could I suggest?

Move initialization inside the success callback.

That is,

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("ads");

                        String Inter = obj.getString("inter");
                        data = Inter;
//HERE YOU NEW CODE

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(data);
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        requestNewInterstitial();
        goToItem(mPosition);
    }
});

requestNewInterstitial();
```

//END OF NEW CODE
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

do not forget to remove this injection from the previous position;)

Comment: I followed the tutorial here, https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/parsing-json-android-using-volley-library/ without using textview method but just giving the calling the admob id and give it a variable then used that variable in admob code but didnt work. but when i put the code directly in the holder data="xxxxx" it works, so it seems like the code can't parse the admob id inside the holder data="" , can you help please

Comment: @user2972389 please, post your android code and http server responce.

Comment: Part1: 
String JsonURL = "http://xxxxxx.com/ads.json";
// This string will hold the results
String data = "";
RequestQueue requestQueue;

Comment: 2nd part:
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
try {
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("ads");
String Inter = obj.getString("inter");
data = Inter;
}
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
 },

Comment: 3rd part:
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(obreq);

and the interstitial calling part of the value id is this:
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(data);

Comment: Use `ActivityName.this` instead of `this` @user2972389

Comment: @user2972389 have a nice day!:)